# MFC application Crashing at crtexe.c on action of alt+tab

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

i have written dialogue based application .and on init of dialogue i have added multiple Frames and opening as FramewndEx as main-entry of point of application.

an Action of alt +tab application got crashed suddenly and its showing cursor at crtexe.c

```
comctl32.dll!MasterSubclassProc()  + 0x4f81 bytes   
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()  + 0x13e bytes 
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  + 0x1a7 bytes   
mfc100u.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  + 0x52 bytes  
mfc100u.dll!CWinThread::Run()  + 0x6f bytes 
mfc100u.dll!AfxWinMain()  + 0xac bytes
```

> RockEye.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 547 + 0x24 bytes  C
>       kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()  + 0x1a bytes
>       ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()  + 0x21 bytes

i am new to this type of situations. i am very struck here.

Comment: Go up the function call stack until you come to your code. Also, you are debugging with the "Debug" variant?

Comment: Yes .i am debugging the same..

Comment: Your problem seems related in `WM_PAINT`, `WM_SIZE` message. Are you using redrawing or changing size function? such as `Invalidate()`, `MoveWindow()`. First of all, before adding **multiple Frames**, check whether your dialog is normal.

Comment: And then, add only `one frame` and check, again, where everything is ok.

Comment: ok.let me check with one frame.

Comment: yes it meight be,.i am using docuable pane windows. to frameex.and  as per implementation we used invalide window when its going to be docked